# Как скрыть, что ты зашёл через selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Использую **chromedriver**.

Как скрыть от сайта, что ты зашел на него при помощи Selenium?

```
option = Options()
option.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\donch\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 3')

option.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=option)

driver.get("https://vavadaret5.com/ru/profile/bonus")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "через selenium"? Вы используете браузер. Браузер посылает запрос. Сайт не может достоверно определить, как именно вы отправили запрос. По поводу ошибки — думаю, вы просто не авторизовались, войдите в свой профиль

Comment: я зашёл в аккаунт как раз таки

Comment: Захожу просто через хром, захожу в аккаунт и всё нормально
а захожу через selenium сразу ошибка

Comment: Вы через selenium авторизовались? Или указали драйверу что хотите использовать какую либо из предыдущих сессий Google Chrom браузера? Для начала нужно прочитать документацию по инструменту с которым вы начинаете работать.

Comment: Драйвер не использует данные браузера Chrome куки и всё остальное, а создаёт новое подключение, и серверу это не нравится, IP один и тот же, браузер то же вроде как один и тот же, но данные он шлёт не основываясь на предыдущей сессии а как будто вы первый раз зашли на сайт. Из этого сервер делает вывод что вас проще послать.

Comment: Дак я через селениум не могу даже зайти на тот сайт

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что имеете ввиду --option
Детектирование Seleniuma встречал несколько раз, но всегда решал опциями.
Вот список опций для информации [Список опций Selenium](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)